# Generate an "INSERT INTO" script from SQL Server to Postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I need to generate a script with the data from one db in sql server to postgres. It seems the "Generate Script" in SQL Management doesn't do ANSI format like `INSERT INTO` that I need.

How can I do it?

Comment: Generate the script in SQL Server.  Edit it to work for Postgres.

Comment: I don't think this is a database problem. I think this is a SQL Management export option.

Comment: If your Postgres server runs on Linux, you can link your Postgres server to SQL Server directly using the [foreign data wrapper for SQL Server](https://github.com/GeoffMontee/tds_fdw)

Comment: What is your actual goal?  To generate the script, to move data to a server you control, or to serialize data to a server you don't control?

Comment: Dump the data to CSV from SQL server then COPY to table in pg

Answer (score 0):

I suggest.

1. Fire up an instance of Postgres on an accessible device.
2. Set up a linked server from Microsoft SQL Server to access the postgresql server using the postgres 64 bit odbc driver.
3. Start writing TSQL to transfer the data.

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=postgresql+odbc+sql+server+2012